# Python thread that opens subprocess not joining until I press Enter

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

My program is supposed to run a subprocess in the background and wait for the user to press Enter.  When the user presses Enter, an empty file is created at a predetermined path.  The mere existence of this empty file signals the subprocess to terminate gracefully.  (I have verfied that this termination based on the file's existence works correctly.)

In my `controller` function, I spawn a thread (`threading.Thread`) that runs the subprocess using `subprocess.Popen`.  Then, in `controller`, I await user input (Enter), and then create the special file to terminate the subprocess, and finally join on the spawned thread.

Things seem to be working fine with 1 problem: after I press Enter and the termination sequence runs, I have to press Enter 1 more time to get past the thread join.  That is, in order to reach the `pdb.set_trace()` statement below, I have to press Enter twice.

**What could be forcing me to press Enter twice here?**

*Clue:* When I remove the `raw_input` statement, the program terminates directly (which is the expected behaviour when not waiting for user input to terminate).

```
def controllerSubprocess(command):
    subprocess.call(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


def controller(parms): 

    # Defined "command" here.

    ret_stdout = []
    controller_subproc_thread = threading.Thread(target=controllerSubprocess,
                                                 args=(command,))
    controller_subproc_thread.daemon = False
    controller_subproc_thread.start()
    raw_input('Now running. Press ENTER to finish...')

    print '\nTerminating...'

    # Create an empty file that causes the process
    # opened by subprocess to end after roughly 5 seconds.

    controller_subproc_thread.join()

    pdb.set_trace()
```

Comment: My first instinct is that you are calling `proc.communicate()` twice, once for stdout and once for stderr.

Comment: @d_kennetz I switched to `subprocess.call` to avoid this complication. But same problem.  Updated my code above.